# How to globalize/translate numbers in Angular based on locale

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, globalization, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate library to take care of localization support in my Angular8 app. In one specific feature module, it is required to show row numbers for each row of the table. There is also an option to create a new row and the newly created row should have a row number which is the next integer that follows the previous row number.

Is it possible to localize the row numbers being displayed depending on the user locale (both the existing row numbers and the dynamically created row numbers). So, if the locale is 'en_US' and the row number is "twelve", it should be displayed as "12" whereas for Chinese locale the row number should be displayed as "十二".